# How to make Stories ignore EmptyOptionalValue

Tags: bixby

I have a problem testing my stories now because whenever an optional value is missing from the data I retrieve from an external database, the Story engine treats it as an Execution Fail. This is making it hard for me to automate my testing.  These results are actually fine, the available content is being displayed as intended.  Is there a way I can get around this so that the Story tester treats these as successful?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it seems not related to the story.

In the debugger, at the end of action, it is already showing error. The view or result might be fine, but to Bixby Planner, there is unhandled error. You may want to double check JS file to do a validation check to all fields from external database.

You can either post your JS file here or raise a support ticket to us to further exam the issue. I will update answer once learned more about the JS file.